# Javascript function to add to or splice array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, splice

I have two buttons, each button adds an array to the array orderArray. This works fine and the array is displayed as a html table. When the table is output a button is also created. This buttons purpose is to remove the array associated with it, and hence remove a line from the table.

This works fine, but after removing part of the array with .splice it is not possible to then add more to the array, it just throws "cannot read property length".

You can see in the console that the array is spliced and that the length value is correct but the error still persists. I am clearly not getting something here, as I thought that as the loop calls myArray.length it would get the right length every time.

Here is the js:

```
var orderArray = [];
var orderNumber = 0;
var theOrder = [];
var total = 0;

function orderUpdate(item,price){
    theOrder = [item, price];
    orderArray[orderNumber] = theOrder;
    orderNumber++;
}

function makeTable(myArray) {
    var result = "<table border=2 id=orderTable>";
    console.log(myArray.length);
    for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        result += "<tr id='row" + i + "'>";
        for(var j = 0; j < myArray[i].length; j++){
            result += "<td>" + myArray[i][j] + "</td>";

        }
        result += "<td><button onclick='removeLine(" + i + ")'>Remove</button></td></tr>";
    }
    result += "</table>";
    console.log(myArray);
    return result;
}

$( "#LongB" ).click(function() {
    orderUpdate("Long Black", 2.50);
    $("#ordered").html(makeTable(orderArray));
});

$( "#FlatW" ).click(function() {
    orderUpdate("Flat White", 3.50);
    $("#ordered").html(makeTable(orderArray));
});

function removeLine(arrayIndex){
    orderArray.splice(arrayIndex, 1);
    console.log(orderArray);
    $("#ordered").html(makeTable(orderArray));
}
```

and the html:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>JSPOS</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<button id="LongB">Long Black</button>
<button id="FlatW">Flat White</button>
<h3>Ordered:</h3>
<div id="ordered"></div>

<script src="js/stuff.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and [here](https://jsfiddle.net/purnrntr/) it is as a fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try substituting `orderArray.push(theOrder);` for `orderArray[orderNumber] = theOrder;`

```
function orderUpdate(item,price){
    theOrder = [item, price];
    orderArray.push(theOrder);
    // orderNumber++;
}
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/purnrntr/2/

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are increasing the `orderNumber` when you add new item but when you remove the item you forgot to decrease the `orderNumber` so you got the error because index doesn't exists in array:-

```
function removeLine(arrayIndex){
orderArray.splice(arrayIndex, 1);
console.log(orderArray);
 orderNumber--; //add this line
$("#ordered").html(makeTable(orderArray));
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/purnrntr/1/)

Comment: You beat me by 32 seconds and that's got me 2 downvotes. Great.

Comment: Also, you could just use `push` to add and `splice` to delete (which you already did) and let JS do the counting. Using `orderArray.push(theOrder);` should be enough.

Comment: well i just explain why he got that error otherwise there are many better ways to do same functionality